# Boto3: Lambda Get lastRecordedPullTime in the return

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, boto3, amazon-ecr

As specified in Boto3 documentation, if I use [describe_image](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ecr.html#ECR.Client.describe_images) I should get a of informations, more importantly, lastRecordedPullTime.

But when I use it in my Lambda, I only get a little 8 out of 11 informations.
When I use aws-cli, I do get all the informations, included lastRecordedPullTime.

Did I miss something ?

```
dictKwarg = {'nextToken':nextTk, 'maxResults':1000, 'repositoryName':repository}
images = ecrClient.describe_images(**dictKwarg)
for img in images['imageDetails']:
    for k,v in img.items():
        print(f"{k}")
```

returns:

1. registryId
2. repositoryName
3. imageDigest
4. imageTags
5. imageSizeInBytes
6. imagePushedAt
7. imageManifestMediaType
8. artifactMediaType

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`boto3` in a lambda function is **not a full version** and often its not up to date. Thus, it is quite common for some parameters and attributes to be missing. Thus, you should bundle latest `boto3` in your function yourself, for example in a lambda layer.

If you do not want to make your own layer, you can try using publicly available ones, such as from [here](https://github.com/keithrozario/Klayers).

Comment: Thanks, it  makes much more sens now. I'll try to make my own layer. Thanks for the link too.

Comment: Worked for me, made a new layer following : https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/lambda-python-runtime-errors/

Thanks a lot !